# Nuitka on Windows

Tags: mingw, python-3.4, windows-7-x64, anaconda, nuitka

Having problems to compile hello-world.py using Nuitka on windows.

The command I am using is:

```
nuitka --standalone --portable --remove-output --recurse-all --python-version=3.4 hello_world.py
```

The error is:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
File "C:\Users\win_user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\SingleExe.scons", line 866:
shell       = False
File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709:
errread, errwrite)
File "c:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957:
startupinfo)
```

Same code compiles & runs fine on Linux. Same code runs fine in interpreter on windows.

The files mentioned in the error message do actually exist. Any suggestions?

Using Win7. Python 3.4 (Anaconda x64). Using MinGW.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, for the benefit of anyone who has the same error, here is the answer to my own question:

I failed to get MinGW working. I eventually got MSVC2010 installed instead. This is maybe better since it is recommended for Python 3.4 on Windows anyway (see: https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows).

**Below are instructions for installing Nuitka using python 3.4 with MSVC++2010 and Win7 64bit:**

Other helpful instructions for MSVC2010 are here: 

1. https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_MSVC2010

2. http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95039-why-does-the-sdk-7-1-installation-fail-with-an-installation-failed-message-on-my-windows-system

Steps are:

1. Install .net 4.x:
   run **dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe** (from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17851)
2. Install Visual C++ 2010 Express:
   run **vc_web.exe** (from http://microsoft-visual-cpp-express.soft32.com/download/file/id/795918/?no_download_manager=true)
3. *UN*-install any Visual C++ 2010 runtime/redistributable newer or equal to 10.0.30319.
   (In my case I had a clean windows install for this setup so there was nothing to remove)
4. Install Windows SDK 7.1: (select all install options)
   run **winsdk_web.exe** (from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
5. Install VS 2010 SP1:
   run **VS10sp1-KB983509.exe** (from http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
6. Install MSVC 2010 SP1 Compiler Update:
    
   run **VC-Compiler-KB2519277.exe** (from http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=4422)

C compiler now installed.

7. To test on 64 bit machines I found that there is a file missing, which has to be manually created. (See here: http://www.w7forums.com/threads/vcvarsall-bat-no-64bit-support-vcvars64-bat-missing.6606/)
   To fix create a file called: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\vc\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat**
   In the file put the text **CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64**
8. Set-up environment:
   run **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall" amd64**
   Console text should go yellow after above command.
   (See here for options other than amd64: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx)
9. Compile test program: (do this while cmd text is still yellow)
   **cl hello.c**
   (assuming your test program is called *hello.c*)
10. Run test program: 
    **hello.exe**

C compiler now tested.

11. Install python 2.7: (Nuitka needs this even if the python code is 3.x)
    run **python-2.7.6.amd64.msi** (from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.amd64.msi)
12. Install python 3.4: (Anaconda stack seems to be the sanest way to get this on Windows)
    run **Anaconda3-2.3.0-Windows-x86_64.exe** (from https://3230d63b5fc54e62148e-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda3-2.3.0-Windows-x86_64.exe)
13. Install Nuitka: (newer versions all the time so better check http://nuitka.net/pages/download.html)
    run **Nuitka-5.1.143.win-amd64.py34.msi** (from http://nuitka.net/releases/Nuitka-5.1.143.win-amd64.py34.msi)

All install now done!

14. Test Nuitka: (assuming your test program is *hello.py*)
    **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall" amd64**
    **nuitka --standalone --portable hello.py**
    **cd hello.dist**
    **hello.exe**

On the first usage of nuitka it gave this notice: "Nuitka will make use of Dependency Walker (http://dependencywalker.com) tool to analyze the dependencies of Python extension modules. Is it OK to download and put it in APPDATA (no installer needed, cached, one time question). Proceed and download? [Yes]/No". I said yes and then the hello world program worked.

Hello world worked after this procedure but some imports on more complicated programs cause warnings. Will edit my answer when I figure that one out. Or will ask another question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Note: The above seems to work fine for simple programs but is not tested fully. Note also that strictly speaking Nuitka requires VS 2015, but seems to work ok with 2010 express as above.

Comment: I'm not having the same luck, seems like some downloads above are no longer working/listed.  It would be fantastic if there was a VM (for windows) that had everything working already for nuitka-- I've wasted enough time trying to get it to behave.

Comment: Now nuitka requires Visual Studio / Build Tools 2019